# Liferay Import LDAP users multiple base dn

Tags: ldap, liferay, liferay-6

I have to import users from two different base dn. My Users lie in following structures

ou=users,ou=dev,dc=abc,dc=net
ou=users,ou=qa, dc=abc,dc=net

Rest of the properties like base.provider.url and security credentials are same for both. What is the correct way to import and authenticate users from both the above DNs in Liferay.

Right now i have provided properties like this in portal-ext.properties

```
ldap.base.provider.url.0=ldap://localhost:10389
ldap.base.dn.0=ou=users,ou=dev,dc=abc,dc=net
ldap.security.principal.0=username
ldap.security.credentials.0=password

ldap.base.provider.url.1=ldap://localhost:10389
ldap.base.dn.1=ou=users,ou=qa,dc=abc,dc=net
ldap.security.principal.1=username
ldap.security.credentials.1=password
```

Is it the correct way of importing and authenticating in my scenario. It seems to work intermittently. That is sometimes user is authenticated against ldap and sometimes it is not. I have not changed any settings from Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into following link it may help you..

Instead of using portal-ext.properties file use Admin Control panel to configure LDAP.

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/10/liferay-ldap-integration_8.html

Comment: Once if you use this, it takes precedence over portal-ext.properties. Admin panel does not support all the properties. For example if you want to map Liferay's custom attribute with an LDAP attribute, it can only be done using portal-ext.properties. If you use Admin panel, Liferay wont use the additional properties set for LDAP that are available just in portal-ext.properties